# Llamada Sincrona en AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

estoy usando AngularJS y quiero obtener los datos del servidor y después de recuperarlos que re-diriga el angular a otra parte.

```
function _getCertificate(redirectPath) {
                $rootScope.myCertificate = true;
                var uriDataCertificado = 'ruta';
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: uriDataCertificado,
                    cache: false
                }).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (null !== response.data && response.status === 200) {
                            if (null != response.data.url && response.data.url !== "") {
                                var authTokenOP = $base64.encode($rootScope.userJavaService + ':' + $rootScope.passJavaService);
                                $http({
                                    method: 'GET',
                                    url: response.data.url,
                                    cache: false,
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + authTokenOP
                                    }
                                }).then(function (response) {
                                    if (!response.data) {
                                        $rootScope.myCertificate = false;
                                        $location.path(redirectPath);
                                    }
                                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                                    $rootScope.myCertificate = false;
                                    $location.path(redirectPath);
                                });
                            } else {
                                $rootScope.myCertificate = false;
                                $location.path(redirectPath);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
            _getCertificate(redirectPath);
```

Con este trozo de código donde hago el $location.path dentro de lo que ocurre en la llamada, no se ejecuta el $location.path y me deja en la pantalla donde estaba.

Por otro lado si lo quito y lo pongo después de llamar a la función (ejemplo)

```
else {
                                    $rootScope.myCertificate = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
                _getCertificate();
                $location.path(redirectPath);
```

Llevará a la otra ventana, mientras se ejecuta el ajax.
Necesito que no vaya a la otra ventana hasta que no termine de procesar la llamada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que hacer que tu funcion _getCertificate devuelva una promesa y en el método `resolve()` le pasas como parametro los datos que devuelve tu llamada http y en caso de error haces un `reject()` al cual tambien puedes pasar un parámetro si lo necesitas.

```
function _getCertificate(redirectPath) {
    ...
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        $http({
        ...
            resolve(parametroOpcional) //reject()
```

Y donde llamas a la función para obtener el certificado haces un `then()` para que todo el código dentro de la función que le pasas al then por parámetro solo se ejecute una vez se ha resuelto la función de la promesa, en tu caso `_getCertificate()`.

```
_getCertificate().then(function (resolveParameter) {
    $location.path(redirectPath); 
    //redirectPath podría ser resolveParameter mandado desde el resolve de la otra función por ejemplo
});
```